How to only allow releases to create tags in GitHub
How do I make sure only a GitHub release can create a tag on my repository.
In GitHub we use releases to create tags. I added a rullset to my repository to protect my tags name and protect is from deletion and updating. However if I protect it from being created, then also my releases can no longer create a tag.
I tried to add an additional rull set with a bypass for releases, however I could not find such a bypass.
I also tried to add an github action to protect tag creation, however the action only runs on tag-push, but it does not run. The tag is probably only pushed if the rulles are already met.
